# expressjs returning controller object to res.send

Tags: node.js, express

I have a controller that makes an api call (few seconds delay) and then returns a JSON object that I want to send and appear on my view page. At the moment I am able to return the object and successfully load the route, but the object is not appearing on my browser page (status code: 200) and I'm not sure what I might be missing. Provided below is my route and controller.

**Controller:**

```
var express = require('express');
var apiRouter = express.Router();
var googleAnalytics = require('../google-analytics');
const { checkToken } = require("./components/token-validator");

apiRouter.use(checkToken);

apiRouter.get('/ga', function(req, res){
    res.send(googleAnalytics())
});

module.exports = apiRouter;
```

**Controller (googleAnalytics):**

```
module.exports = () => {
  console.log("google-analytics.js")

  const {google} = require('googleapis');
  const analyticsreporting = google.analyticsreporting('v4');
  const view_id = '*view-id(';

    ... // resource: req information

  analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet({
    resource: req
  }, (err, result) => {
    if(err){
      if(err.errors){
        console.log(err.errors[0].message)
      } else {
        console.log(err)
      }
    } else {
      return result.data;
    }
    //console.log("BREAK IN CONSOLE")
    //console.log(err, result)
  })
}
```

**Object E.g.:**

```
{"reports":[{"columnHeader":{"dimensions":["ga:sourceMedium"],"metricHeader":{"metricHeaderEntries":
...
]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the `google-analytics.js`. You need to make the function return a promise or use callback. `analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet` returns a promise so it is pretty easy to do that.

```
module.exports = () => {
  console.log("google-analytics.js")

  const {google} = require('googleapis');
  const analyticsreporting = google.analyticsreporting('v4');
  const view_id = '*view-id(';

    ... // resource: req information

  return analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet({
    resource: req
  });
}
```

Now, in your `/ga` route, you can use `async-await`:

```
apiRouter.get('/ga', async function(req, res){
    res.send(await googleAnalytics())
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since the returned promise from `analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet` contains all of the methods returned information and all I'm concerned with is the data, I should have no issue updating the code to read `return analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet({
    resource: req
  }).then(function(result){
    return result.data;
  });`. In addition, is the `asnyc-await` used due to the response lag in the API request? This ensures the data is returned before the route is successful?